# ОБЪЯСНИМО равно ПОНЯТНО?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы

В своей книге Рой Медведев пишет, что «Путин пришел к власти, опираясь на силовые структуры. Мне это объяснимо: это был мир, где он провел часть жизни, здесь произошло его становление как члена корпорации».

Смущает это его «*мне это объяснимо*», хотя *объяснимо* и *понятно* — синонимы. Разговорное сочетание проникло в речь писателя и не более?

Comment: Надо так: *для меня это объяснимо*. Хотя оно в принципе либо объяснимо, либо нет, это слово не для субъективности (то есть "мне" лучше вообще выкинуть). Слова не совсем синонимы, одно зависит от другого: понятно, потому что объяснимо.

Comment: Они и через союз неплохо выглядят, а также (вне зависимости) с отрицанием другого: объяснимо, но непонятно.

Comment: Ну да, то есть "объяснимо" не значит "понятно". То есть не синонимы, просто между ними есть взаимосвязь.